# Time update using Calendar

Tags: java, android, time

I have a simple application to show the system time.

Every time I run it, displays and logs only the same time. It is the same time when the application first started.

I can't figure it out why it shows the first same time and doesn't update.

The code is simple:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int y,m,d;

        Date date= new Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


        c.setTime(date);

        y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        Log.d("AAAAA",y + ":" +m+ ":" +d);

        TextView textTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textTime.setText(y + ":" +m+ ":" +d);

    }
```

Comment: What would you *expect* to make it update, and when?

Answer (score 3):

```
    //date instance is created with current system time
    Date date= new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    //you have set that date time into calendar instance
    c.setTime(date);
```

So now if you don't change the data (date) of calendar instance as long as it is alive it will hold the same value that was set